# How to perform function after printing completes?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, documentviewer

I am trying to print a document from a DocumentViewer, with some actions that are necessary before and after the print, like this:

```
private void PrintDocument(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    PrePrintAction();
    MyDocumentViewer.Print();
    PostPrintAction();
}
```

`PrintDocument` gets called when the user presses the 'print' button on the DocumentViewer.

My problem is that the `MyDocumentViewer.Print()` command does not actually physically print anything until the `PrintDocument` function exits, which means that `PostPrintAction` runs *before* the printer actually prints anything. It needs to run after the physical printing has been performed, though.

Can anyone help me to figure out why the printing does not perform until the function exits? And what would be the best way to work around this? I already tried using a BackgroundWorker to run the print command on another thread but didn't really get anywhere with that.

Comment: Print just goes to the print queue.  If it was out of paper would you want it to just wait?  What needs to wait for physical print to complete?

Comment: @Paparazzi It's a spool printer, so after it prints I need to tell the printer to cut and eject the paper. (The Print command does not do that part.)

Comment: Then write a you own print command.  Search on paginator